# Trouble understanding factorial algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I am having trouble understanding some of the algebraic concepts used here. In fact, the entire thing to me makes sense, except for the second red line. I don't understand how the diagonal swap happened there. Why did the (n-1)! on the LHS swap with the (n-3)! on the RHS?

After that all makes sense to me, I just don't get this one bit.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{a}{c}\cdot \frac{c}{b} = \frac{b}{d} \cdot \frac{c}{b}\quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say/demonstrate here. Can you reference a principal or expand on your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They multiply the both sides by $\frac{(n-3)!}{(n-1)!}$.

$$\frac{4(n!)}{(n-3)!}=\frac{5(n-1)!}{(n-1-3)!}$$$$\Rightarrow \frac{4(n!)}{\color{red}{(n-3)!}}\times \frac{\color{red}{(n-3)!}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{5\color{green}{(n-1)!}}{(n-1-3)!}\times\frac{(n-3)!}{\color{green}{(n-1)!}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{4(n!)}{(n-1)!}=\frac{5(n-3)!}{(n-4)!}$$

Comment: I understand why it works now! Though I guess I don't understand immediately why after looking at it why it was clear to make such a multiplication. Based on looking at that equation, why would someone say "its a good idea to multiply it like so". What can I look for in the future?

Comment: @byteofthat: Good question. Let me ask you one question. What do you think is the merit of doing this?

Comment: I can see that it makes the equation easier to work with, but I am not sure how to describe it more technically than that. I think I need some help understanding the true merit in the operation.

Comment: @byteofthat: I think they do this because they found that $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}=n,\frac{(n-3)!}{(n-4)!}=n-3$ which are very easy to do with. All I can say is that we need to look carefully at the both sides at any moment.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks much!